# Powercli Script to measure the count of Host and its Vm's in a each clusters

Tags: vmware-vsphere, powercli

I am trying create a on-liner script which gives an outputs of Hosts and vm's counts in a vcenter cluster like as below.

```
Cluster:                                                      VMHost                         VM's
Cluster01                                                     04                                  15
cluster02                                                      02                                  35
```

Just using a sample onliner

```
Get-VMHost | Select @{N=“Cl“;E={Get-Cluster -VMHost $_}} Name, @{N=“NumVM“;E={($_ | Get-VM).Count}} | Sort Cluster, Name
```

any Ideas?? Thanks in advance

Regards,
Subash.

Comment: Do you NEED to do this via PowerCLI? it's all there in vCenter

Answer (score 0):

A bit long for a one-liner, but here you go ([again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115501/powercli-script-to-count-the-esxi-host-and-its-vms-on-each-clusters)?)

```
get-cluster | select @{n="cluster";e={$_.name}}, @{n="hosts";e={($_ | get-vmhost).count}}, @{n="vms";e={($_ | get-vm).count}} | sort cluster | ft -auto
```

Comment: Next time, maybe mark this as a duplicate and reference the other answer..

Comment: @GregL Seems like the duplicate must be on ServerFault, rather than SO. Offhand the question seems like a better fit for SO. Certainly it's presented more clearly there, though of course that's easily fixed here.